# Query with no records returns null for SUM function

Tags: mysql, sql

This query will return you 0 records if no records exist in TableA:

```
Select strA, strB, intC, floatD, from tableA
```

However, this query returns 1 records with all columns as Null.

```
Select strA, strB, intC, floatD, sum(intC+intD) as sumE,
from tableA
```

So, to fix it, I did:

```
Select strA, strB, intC, floatD, sum(intC+intD) as sumE,
from tableA
having sumE is not null
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do the same thing. Any in-built MySQL function that can do the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

That's because you don't have a `GROUP BY`. You're asking MySQL to get you the `SUM` of `intC + intD` for the entire table, so it's going to give you a result no matter what. It has to put in something for `strA, strB`, etc. so it puts in `NULL` values.

For example, just do `SELECT SUM(intA) FROM tableA` and you'll get `NULL`.